# On the probability of the multivariate normal with fixed pairwise correlations being coordinate-wise non-negative

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

This problem itself, admittedly, is not a research problem; but rather an intermediate step I've encountered in my research.

Let $(X_i:1\le i\le N)$  be a multivariate normal random vector where i) each coordinate $X_i$ is standard normal and ii) $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]=\rho$ for every $1\le i<j\le N$.

My question. Is there a symbolic expression (as a function of $N$ and $\rho$ only) for the following probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_1\ge 0,X_2\ge 0,\dots,X_N\ge 0\right).
$$
Some further notes:

- For $N=2$, using the fact $X_1$ and $\frac{X_2-\rho X_1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$ are i.i.d. standard normal, one can indeed reach to $\frac14+\frac{\sin^{-1}\rho}{2\pi}$.
- For $N=3$, such formulas are available in standard textbooks, and is given by $\frac18+\frac{3\sin^{-1}\rho}{4\pi}$.

Situation gets more involved beyond $N\ge 4$.

**Edit.** Looking at the structure of the solution for $N=2$ and $N=3$, I postulate that the answer is
$$
\frac{1}{2^N}+\binom{N}{2}\frac{\sin^{-1}\rho}{\eta}
$$
where
$$
\eta = \binom{N}{2}\pi \frac{2^{N-1}}{2^{N-1}-1}.
$$
My rationale is a) for $\rho=0$ it must be $2^{-N}$ as everybody is independent, b) the term, $\sin^{-1}\rho$, should appear exactly once for each pair $1\le i<j\le N$, and c) for $\rho=1$, it should be $\frac12$.

This obviously simplifies to
$$
2^{-N}+\frac{\sin^{-1}\rho\left(2^{N-1}-1\right)}{2^{N-1}\pi}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g., [Ruben, formulas (102) and (102') on p. 220](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2333017?seq=1) has a recurrence for your probability
$$
p_n:=P(X_1\ge0,\dots,X_n\ge 0).
$$
It is stated there, on p. 213: "For dimensionality greater than three (spherical tetrahedra, spherical pentahedra, etc.) the areas can no longer be expressed in terms of elementary functions."
See also e.g. [Plackett](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332716?origin=crossref&seq=1) and references there for more general results.

---

Anyhow, your conjectured expression for $p_n$ cannot be true in general. Indeed, the eigenvalues of your covariance matrix of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ are $1+(n-1)\rho$ (with the eigenspace spanned by the vector $\mathbf1:=(1,\dots,1)$) and $1-\rho$. Since the covariance matrix must be positive semidefinite, necessarily $1+(n-1)\rho\ge0$, that is, $\rho\ge-1/(n-1)$.

In particular, if $\rho=-1/(n-1)$, then the random point $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is with probability $1$ on the hyperplane passing through the origin and orthogonal to the vector $\mathbf1$. Therefore, then $p_n=0$, which does not agree with your conjectured expression for $p_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Others who have looked at this problem found no closed-form expression. E.g., Shanti Gupta [surveyed](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177704004) results in this area in 1963; he said on p. 800: "the integrals can be evaluated in closed form for n=1, 2, and 3."

Answer (score 0):

When $\rho > 0$ such r.v.s can be represented as $Z + X_i$ where $Z$ independent normal and the $X_i$ are i.i.d. normal and you can immediately write  down a one dimensional integral for the expression you are looking for, but I personally can't integrate it, except maybe  in case $Z$ has the same distribution as well, which is  $\rho = .5$ and for which I get 1/(N+1).  You might browse things related to a model  of Vasicek, which is described here: http://dse.univr.it/safe/documents/SSEFCANAZEI2012/07_correlation_-_modeling.pdf

Comment: What is the one-dimensional integral for this?